# Rename [google-sites] -> [google-classic-sites] / [google-sites-2016] -> [google-sites]

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request

The request is to realize a coordinated rename of two tags:

1. [google-sites](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-sites) to [google-classic-sites](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-classic-sites)
2. [google-sites-2016](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-sites-2016) to [google-sites](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-sites)

---

Screen shown to users having a consumer account, i.e. @gmail.com when accessing https://sites.google.com/site/

[image]

> Creating and editing in Classic Sites is no longer supported. Your classic sites will be automigrated to new sites.  [Learn more](https://support.google.com/a/answer/9958187)

As of January 31th, 2023, the message for users having a Workspace account is

> Editing in Classic Sites will be turned off starting on 1/30/23. Act now to review and migrate from Classic Sites to New Sites.  [Learn more](https://support.google.com/a/answer/9958187)

---

- [google-sites](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-sites) has 757 questions. This is about Google "classic Sites". It used to support [google-gadget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-gadget) and there is a Google Apps Script service to handle tasks on "classic Sites" like create pages, update content, etc. This tag needs some clean up as there are some questions about some Google API / product and about some sort of website (i.e. GitHub pages) that are not related with "classic Sites".

  Users having consumer accounts, i.e. gmail.com, can't no longer create / edit "classic Sites". Google have annonced that since September 2021 "classic Sites" will no longer viewable by anyone but there are still some sites that are viewable (some of my sites are viewable).

  According to the docs from Google, starting on January 30, 2023, Workspace users will not able to edit "classic Sites" and they will be archived as HTML files in the site owner's Google Drive.
- [google-sites-2016](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-sites-2016) has 59 questions. It is about the Google "new Sites". Some sites created with Google "classic Sites" were migrated automatically to this new platform. The new platform doesn't support all the features the "classic Sites", there is no Google Apps Script service. "new Sites" allow the use of HTML / CSS / JavaScript with some limitations and allow to embed web apps created using Google Apps Script by pasting the web app URL.

  There are several "recent" questions (probably since 2016) having [google-sites](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-sites) that should be tagged [google-sites-2016](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-sites-2016). Most of the questons having [google-sites](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-sites) posted since November 2022 (I haven't reviewed older questions) are not a good fit for this site. Some ask for recommendations, some needs details, some belongs to other sites like Webmasters or Web Applications (aren't related to programming) but there are few of them that are good enough to keep the tag.

Once it's confirmed that Google have turned off the editing of all "classic Sites", I think that a "full" clean-up might realized, i.e.:

- Close as no repro questions about "classic Sites" that imply to access the old "classic Sites" host as this will no longer be possible.
- Retag to assign the correct tag(s).
- Etc.

but that might be discussed later. For now, let focus on the tags rename.

References

- [Transition from classic Sites to new Sites](https://support.google.com/a/answer/9958187)
- [Sites Service | Google Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/sites)

Comment: It's also good to consider just one tag: [google-sites] for everything, since there will be no more questions about [google-classic-sites]

Comment: @TheMaster What about if we try that first and just in case of having to much confussion then split again? Assumption: Most of the people asking about Google Sites are new users and their research efforts are minimal and centered on Youtube rather than SO posts is very unlikely that posts about new Sites will be quoting posts about classic Sites.

Comment: ... or just update the tag excerpts to suggest to use [google-sites] for new Sites and classic Sites.

Comment: @TheMaster the legacy platform might be dead and not getting any more questions, but some (all?) of it's answers will be wrong for the new platform.  That means we need to keep them separate.

Comment: I agree with the suggested change of google-sites-2016 to google-sites, and google-sites to google-classic-sites.